# Azure Function AppSettings using Terraform and mutliple sources for map

Tags: azure, function, terraform, settings, azure-keyvault

so in summary I am specifically looking to maintain the app settings for my azure functions using two different sources,

1. the first source is a map of custom settings that will be maintained manually or through code which might have little change
2. The second source of app settings map are key secret uri's as per the code before, this enables the azure function to use secret references as configuration value.

I am trying to automate the process of retrieving a subset of secrets dynamically from keyvault and merging it into the custom map app settings that I define in code.

**Question:**
My ideal world would be that i update the list `secretKeys` and the map `appSettingsSecretsMap` get's dynamically created and then consumed by resource creation `resource "azurerm_function_app" "functionApp_workerFunctions"` in its appsettings. Does anyone have a idea of how I might achieve this a bit more dynamically?

**My full code is as per below:**

```
variable "secretKeys" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    "TestDbPassword",
    "TestDbUserId"]
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault" {
  name                = "source-keyvault"
  resource_group_name = "source-keyvault-rg"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "kvSecrets" {
  for_each = toset(var.secretKeys)
  name         = each.key
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id
}

# Testing Access to secret
output "TestDbPassword" {
    value = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.kvSecrets["TestDbPassword"].id
} 

#https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references
variabe "appSettingsSecretsMap" {    
    type = map
    default = {
        DBPassword = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.kvSecrets["TestDbPassword"].id})"
        DBUserId = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.kvSecrets["TestDbUserId"].id})"
    }
}

# Reference for appSettings https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings
variable "appSettingsCustomMap" {
  type = map
  default = {
    WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE       = ""
    FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME       = ""
    APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY = ""
    #FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION = "~1"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_function_app" "functionApp_workerFunctions" {
  name                       = "worker-function-${var.ENVIRONMENT}"
  location                   = "XYZ-Example"
  resource_group_name        = "XYZ-Example"
  app_service_plan_id        = "XYZ-Example"
  storage_account_name       = "XYZ-Example"
  storage_account_access_key = "XYZ-Example"
  app_settings               = merge(var.appSettingsMap, var.appSettingsSecretsMap)
}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For the custom settings, I think it's better to set it in variable manually. It has a lot of things with a little change. If you make it automated, I think it will be a little redundancy. Just do it as you show in the question.
2. For key fault, I recommend you use the [`locals`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) block:

```
    locals {
        appSettingsSecretsMap = {
            DBPassword = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.kvSecrets[0].id})"
        DBUserId = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.kvSecrets[1].id})"
        }
    }
```

The data for the key vault secrets will return a list with the element like this:

[image]

So you cannot quote it with the secret name. Just do it as what I show you.

Comment: hey thank you for your reply Charles, is it actually possible to build the appSettingsSecretsMap using a loop referencing the intial `secretKeys` values?

Comment: @Sl-NZ What do you mean the "initial `secretKeys` values"?

Comment: Using this list variable named `secretKeys`  which is just a key reference.

```
variable "secretKeys" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    "TestDbPassword",
    "TestDbUserId"]
}
```

Comment: @Sl-NZ The list is used to get the secret via the data source. And when you got the secrets, you can use Terraform function [`zipmap()`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/zipmap.html) as `zipmap(var.secretKeys, data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.kvSecrets[*].id)`, it also can achieve it.

Comment: @Sl-NZ That's OK.