# Add list of configs in app_settings configuration block

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions, azure-rm-template, azure-rm

In terraform I declared a function_app resource:

```
resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "func" {
  name                = local.func_app_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  
  service_plan_id = azurerm_service_plan.asp.id
  
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.sa.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.sa.primary_access_key

  app_settings = {
    key1 = "value1"
    key2 = "value2"
  }

}
```

But i have a new requirements to add a new settings to app_settings.

New settings are placed in list because i iterate over it in another place in a code:

```
locals {
     publish_topics = {
       topicTest = "topic1",
       topicDev  = "topic2"
  }
}
```

How to add static values and values from a list from `locals` to app_settings config?

Comment: Your `locals` has a syntax error. Please update the question with the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add list of configs in app_settings configuration block:

*Use below terraform code to achieve your requirement.*

```bash
locals {
    publish_topics = {
       topic1 = "topic1"
       topic2 = "topic2"
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "xxxx"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "jahservice-plan"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  os_type             = "Windows"
  sku_name            = "Y1"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa" {
  name                     = "xxx"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}
resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "func" {
  name                = "newfuncj"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  
  service_plan_id = azurerm_service_plan.example.id
  
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.sa.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.sa.primary_access_key

  app_settings = merge(
    {
      key1 = "value1"
      key2 = "value2"
    },
    { for topic in local.publish_topics : 
          "topic:${topic}" => topic 
    }
  )
}
```

[image]

[image]

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63326247/azure-function-appsettings-using-terraform-and-mutliple-sources-for-map) for relevant usage of `locals` block and retrieving it using `foreach`.

Update:

You can also use

`for key, value in local.publish_topics : key => value` as suggested by @michasaucer.

Comment: Thanks! But how to keep original values from the list from locals? I want to keep `key = value` schema

Comment: If you can see my output screenshot, the original values key1,key2 with their values are also existed. Is that the one you are asking about? @michasaucer

Comment: well not really. Ofcourse i anonimized some thing but ideal, value and key is different. Thats my bad but u assumed that value and key is the same, am i right?

Comment: Not exactly. I did not assume both value and keys are same. I was saying that the original ones won't get disturbed. Is it changing anything after adding the new ones? @michasaucer

Comment: I edited my question. So i am talking about scenario in `locals` block when i want to keep config like `Topic:topicTest  = topic1` in app config

Comment: As per my understanding, you are talking about this line of code `"topic:${topic}" => topic ` . If you want to inject exact values and keys you can simply give `"${topic}" => topic ` in for loop. So that keys and values will display accurately as shown in the [image](https://i.imgur.com/mzCszXa.png). @michasaucer

Comment: I maanged to do that via: `for key, value in local.publish_topics : key => value`

Comment: Can you edit your answer please to include my comment?

Comment: Is this the one you want me to add `for key, value in local.publish_topics : key => value`. @michasaucer

Comment: yes indeed, to make answer complete